# Uploading Files w/ Firebase SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

EDIT –– This is part of a script that is running on Digital Ocean, parsing PDF files. I'm therefore using Firebase Admin SDK access because I'm running this on a server. At the end of the day, I'd like to be able to upload files to my online storage depot, basically uploading files to a publicly accessible URL that I can then send out to the relevant users.

I've manually uploaded a file into my storage here: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/federal-register.appspot.com/o/nj.jpg?alt=media&token=891a1574-7cc0-44c1-a954-6dcc0844f796

I'd like to be able to programmatically upload files from my server to the storage section of Firebase and make them publicly accessible as well (like this jpeg).

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION –––

I'm trying to upload files (PDF files) to my firebase storage with Node.js using the Firebase Admin SDK.  I'm already using the database successfully with the Admin SDK, but am a little confused by the Storage bit...

Here's how I have my admin SDK configured right now:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../keys/admin.key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://federal-register.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "federal-register.appspot.com/"
});

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
```

If I log out the bucket to the console, I get a complicated object with all sorts of access control list information:

```
Bucket {
  name: 'federal-register.appspot.com/',
  storage: Storage {},
  userProject: undefined,
  acl:
   Acl {
     owners:
      { addAllAuthenticatedUsers: [Function],
        deleteAllAuthenticatedUsers: [Function],
        addAllUsers: [Function],
        deleteAllUsers: [Function],
        addDomain: [Function],
        deleteDomain: [Function],
        addGroup: [Function],
        deleteGroup: [Function],
        addProject: [Function],
        deleteProject: [Function],
        addUser: [Function],
        deleteUser: [Function] },
     readers:
      { addAllAuthenticatedUsers: [Function],
        deleteAllAuthenticatedUsers: [Function],
        addAllUsers: [Function],
        deleteAllUsers: [Function],
        addDomain: [Function],
        deleteDomain: [Function],
        addGroup: [Function],
        deleteGroup: [Function],
        addProject: [Function],
        deleteProject: [Function],
        addUser: [Function],
        deleteUser: [Function] },
     writers:
      { addAllAuthenticatedUsers: [Function],
        deleteAllAuthenticatedUsers: [Function],
        addAllUsers: [Function],
        deleteAllUsers: [Function],
        addDomain: [Function],
        deleteDomain: [Function],
        addGroup: [Function],
        deleteGroup: [Function],
        addProject: [Function],
        deleteProject: [Function],
        addUser: [Function],
        deleteUser: [Function] },
     pathPrefix: '/acl',
     request_: [Function: bound wrapper],
     default:
      Acl {
        owners: [Object],
        readers: [Object],
        writers: [Object],
        pathPrefix: '/defaultObjectAcl',
        request_: [Function: bound wrapper] } },
  iam:
   Iam {
     request_: [Function: bound wrapper],
     resourceId_: 'buckets/federal-register.appspot.com/' } }
```

I've read that this is basically "wrapping" the functionality referred to in the g-cloud documentation. Essentially, firebase is wrapping the g-cloud. I've attempted to use the appropriate g-cloud function (here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) to upload my document, but with no luck.

```
   bucket.upload(filePath);
```

However, I get back an error: `(rejection id: 1): ApiError: Error during request.`

I was attracted to Firebase because of its relative ease-of-use and I'd rather not have to install and learn Google's cloud architecture if I don't have to––especially if Firebase is already wrapping it and giving me access via the Firebase Admin SDK...

**Is there a way that I can upload files with just the Firebase SDK?** If this is not possible, am I correct in assuming I'd have to install the Google module (npm install --save @google-cloud/storage) and then access the methods that way?

Thanks.

Comment: Firebase Storage is Cloud Storage. However, you are using the Firebase Admin SDK. You want to use the Firebase SDK. Edit your question and include details such as you want storage access from the client or you will be managing storage at the server for the client. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Comment: This is part of a script that's running on my server, so I need to use the admin SDK.  I was hoping to use it to upload PDF files to the Firebase storage, which I could then make publicly accessible––is that a bad way of handling this use-case?

Comment: From a security / management standpoint doing everything at the server is best. For the real world, you want to enable clients to do the work. The Firebase SDK has good client support, retries, etc. For the server side use the Google Cloud SDK. Remember use the right tool for the job whenever possible.

Comment: Based upon the update to your question: "Do you want to use a web browser to connect to your server and then click the upload button to directly upload files from your server (that are stored on your server) to Cloud Storage? If yes, then you will want to write a REST endpoint on your server that your web browser calls via Ajax / JQuery. This endpoint then executes a function to upload a file from server storage to Cloud Storage. You will also want to implement authentication.

Comment: @JohnHanley Apologies if that wasn't clear––this is part of a larger script (essentially a long .then chain) that runs on a crontab on my server. So there's no need for client interaction. Basically as I understand it then, you're suggesting that I ditch the Firebase SDK for this and use the Google Cloud SDK instead? If I do this, is there an easy way to make these resources public? I was hoping to avoid going away from Firebase but it sounds like you're suggesting that I do that...

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I do not understand your question / objective as written. Consider reviewing your question to fill in the exact details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll try rewriting it with much more detail...

Comment: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File) for using google cloud storage, firebase and nodejs, if you find it difficult to implement, please let me know in the comments that I make a response.